# How to automate jQuery text content carousel?

Tags: jquery, pagination, carousel, autorotate

I hope somebody could help me with automation of the content carousel I have.

This carousel has a simple dotted pagination and everything works just fine except I can't figure how to automate it so the content changes automatically.

Unfortunately, the full working script is too long to drop it here so I created the [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nWpK8/10/)

Could anybody help to modify the script to include the autorotate feature?

Thanks a lot!

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
            $('.slidewrap').carousel({
                slider: '.slider',
                slide: '.slide',
                addNav: false,
                addPagination: true,
                speed: 300 // ms.                   
            });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add `data-autorotate` attribute to your `div class="slidewrap"`:

```
<div class="slidewrap" data-autorotate="5000">
```

where 5000 is the number of milliseconds to wait for the next slide.

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nWpK8/11/) for a demo.

Comment: oh. that's where I had to add it. I was trying to add it to the script that runs the carousel with no luck. Thanks a lot!